# Creating XML Output with Carriage Returns from SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, export, carriage-return

I've written code in SQL Server to create an XML output. However, this exports with no carriage returns.

I initially built a workaround with a replace statement around the entire XML output code that would embed carriage returns between the nodes, but because that only allows me to export a small amount of data at a time, it's not sufficient long-term. When I try to run this on larger datasets, it truncates the text around 65000 characters.

I've tried to cast the entire statement as nvarchar(max) to increase the output size but that doesn't seem to work either. Does anybody have any recommendations for how to do this that isn't just find+replace once the file has already been output from SQL?

Comment: A valid XML document does not depend on carriage returns at all, if it is producing valid xml you should be happy with that, adding carriage returns and formatting XML outlook should be handled with some other application, SQL Server is not the tool for this task.

Comment: I understand that. However, this is based on a client request so it needs to be done one way or another (ideally would be in SQL to make the process easier.)

Comment: Put a plain XML like `<root><a>some content</a><a>more content</a></root>` into a file, all in one single line, and name it *myPlain.xml*. Now open this with any XML viewer you want, even with a browser. You'll get a neatly formatted view. **This is for presentation only** and could even produce severe data errors, if the CR and LF characters are mistaken as content... **So the only advise can be: Don't do that...**

Answer (score 1):

First, I would educate the client first. I would imagine it is to make it human readable, but it also expands the size of the returned set. They will likely stick to their guns, but education often stops people from spending money on stupid crap.

Second, I would not do this in SQL Server. This is a user interface type of task (including service endpoints as "user" interface here) and not a task to be done in the database. Doing it outside of SQL Server gives you better access to the XML DOM, which can help if they are truly CRLF and not the &#__; numeric equivalents. If the later, you will have to do a replace function.

If you HAVE to do this in SQL Server, grab the XML result and then replace. I would do this the easy way and replace > with >CRLF and see if that is acceptable, as it is less time consuming. Without the DOM it is difficult to know the difference between open tags and end tags. You can find the right tag using regex, if you want to go that far, but SQL Server's implementation is not as good as many programming languages, so this will be time consuming.

Ultimately, if they are willing to pay you for something that does not make a difference, then that is their baby, but it is a useless exercise IMO.

Comment: I concur with Gregory's answer except that if you are forced into doing the entire thing in SQL I would probably look at running XSL in SQLCLR. This would come with it own set of problems but at least you can avoid nasty regex or string replacements. Ultimately though, SQL is all about data storag and retreival, it is the client/application that should be doing the processing.

Comment: If you just replace all `>` with `>CRLF` you would change the content of a `<someElement>This is the value</someElement>`. If doing so, you'd have to distinguish between opening and closing tags and - of course you'd have to deal with `<someClosesElement someAttr="xyz" />` too... I think the only advise can be: Don't do that on data layer...